# How to create fast video loading feature like instagram Reel with React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, instagram, react-native-video

How can I create a **fast video consumption** feature like Instagram *Reels*, I have created a simple video player with the help of react-native-video but after every video, it takes time to load that video.

How can I do something like prefetch the video before displaying that video? Also, it should take care of the user's mobile data consumption.

Is there any way to implement this feature in react native?

Comment: I am also finding library for same feature, did you find any library or solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mobile storage to store the next videos into the queue.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32406972)